# isn't / wouldn't be satisfied with

Tags: grammar, word-choice, idiomatic-language

Which one of **isn't** and **wouldn't be** is correct here?

A: My boyfriend thinks I'm spending too much time with my friends.

Later in the conversation...

B: I don't know. I'm just saying I can understand why your boyfriend **isn't / wouldn't be** satisfied with your priorities.

Comment: What difference can you see between the two?

Comment: What I'm uncertain about is if "wouldn't be" could be used too and would be natural or it would sound odd since A has already told B that her boyfriend isn't satisfied.

Comment: Your question seems to assume that one must be 'right' and one 'wrong'. You now say that you think _isn't_ is right, which it is.  However, B might also use _wouldn't be_ to imply that they are only speculating about what the boyfriend really thinks.

Comment: In your *exact* context it doesn't really make any difference, since it's already explicitly stated that the boyfriend ***isn't*** satisfied. But in closely related contexts the choice between "isn't" and "wouldn't be" is governed by that consideration. *I'll tell him my plan tomorrow, but I can't think of any reason why he **wouldn't be** happy with it*. That wouldn't make sense with ***isn't***, because it refers to a "hypothetical" future reaction.